# node pass in strings for grep -f --fixed-strings

Tags: node.js, bash, unix, grep, child-process

I'd like to use `grep --count --fixed-strings needles.txt < haystack.txt` from a Node.js environment.

Instead of having a file for `needles.txt`, I have an array of strings to search, and instead of `haystack.txt` I have a large string/buffer of text.

What's the best combination of `child_process` methods to use?

Something like:

```js
import {spawn} from "child_process";

// haystack to search within
const haystack = "I am \n such a big string, do you\n see me?";
const readable = new Readable();
readable.push(haystack);
readable.push(null);

// the list of needles that would normally go in `--file=needles.txt`
const needles = ["find", "me", "or", "me"];

// spawn `fgrep`
// Q: How do I pass in `needles` as a string?
const fgrep = spawn(`fgrep`, [needles])

// pipe my haystack to fgrep
readable.pipe(fgrep.stdin);
```

[grep documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)

Comment: Is using the `grep` command for the search a hard requirement? Could be done in js

Comment: @Matt thanks - yes, but to be safe, and for background, there are 3000 needles, and very large haystack, and this has been tested as a faster method than other JS methods. I'd be open to other approaches, but still need to figure out this implementation either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `grep` args, `-e` lets you specify multiple patterns:

```
grep -e 1 -e 2
```

The JS for generating the args will be something like:

```
const needles = ["find", "me", "or", "me"];
const grep_pattern_args = needles.reduce((res, pattern) => {
    res.push('-e', pattern)
    return res
}, [])
const grep_args = [ '--count', '--fixed-strings', ...grep_pattern_args ]
```

3000 needles is heading into the territory of hitting [`execve`s length limit of `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` in Linux of 128kiB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument). If you have lengthy needles you may need to write them to a file in any case to be safe.

[`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) is good as you get the writable stream back for `stdin` that you can write to as `haystack` is read/generated (assuming your `Readable` stream example setup is contrived)

```
const stdout = []
const stderr = []
const fgrep = spawn('/usr/bin/fgrep', grep_args, { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'] })
fgrep.on('error', console.error)

// For larger output you can process more on the stream. 
fgrep.stdout.on('data', chunk => stdout.push(chunk))
fgrep.stderr.on('data', chunk => {
  process.stderr.write(chunk)
  stderr.push(chunk)
})

fgrep.on('close', (code) => {
  if (code !== 0) console.error(`grep process exited with code ${code}`)
  stdout.map(chunk => process.stdout.write(chunk))
})

fgrep.stdin.pipe(haystream)
```

Comment: thank you! specifically for that `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` tip to justify using a file